# Acrtiverecord trace

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, scalability

I have implemented a highly available service with zeromq and celluloid. I have been using ActiveRecord for performing IO against Postgresql. The problem I am facing is a Postgres lookup from ActiveRecord at times > 150 ms at during traffic times and for most events during the high traffic 1 - 3 ms for other events. I have about 7 actors in a pool processing events with an ActiveRecord connection pool defined to be 30. The number of active connections don't go beyond 8. I checked the Postgresql logs if it queries take so much time to process and it does not show entries great then a couple milliseconds.

I wanted to know if there was a way in ActiveRecord where I could trace what part is causing this issue. With every actor to perform a lookup I do it in a block.
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do

   #Perform IO calls here...
end`

I saw the benchmark class that has a class method `measure` but wasn't sure if it would be threadsafe and gives me specific details.

Comment: Have you tried [`explain`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain) that will give you an idea of the query plan. The other overhead is AR mapping. If that is too much maybe consider using something that is a bit lighter weight? Not sure exactly what you are doing but `arel`(AR's underlying query interface) as well as `sequel` have provided performance boosts for me in that past for more data intensive queries where the ORM itself was not a strict requirement. Other than that maybe consider caching with `redis`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried `explain` for the query and I don't see anything out of normal. Its a join query on a small data of 100 records. I will try and see if I could introduce caching. Thanks